# "Application not found" when using Pow

Tags: ruby, rack-pow

I have POW installed, but I do not understand how to symlink to my `app`.

The example they use has `/path/to/myapp`. I really don't get what path I put in here.

I have a folder on my desktop that I wanted to use for my development files. Do I put that file path in here?

I know this is basic, but the guides they have online don't clarify this part.

I keep trying to symlink things and the terminal just says that the file exists. And then nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, I had the same problem, but I found the solution.

During the second step, when creating the symlink, make sure you not only provide the path, but also give the symlink folder a name. Otherwise, you have created a folder that doesn't link you to anywhere. Hence in the terminal, telling you the file exist, but it fact it doesn't work.

`ln -s /path/to/myapp myapp`
instead of `ln -s /path/to/myapp`

Check this out: http://osr507doc.sco.com/en/OSUserG/_Creating_link_to_file.html

Answer (score 2):

Symlinks are basically a shortcut to the main folder. So in order for `POW` to work, you will need to create shortcut of your directory in `.pow` directory. That's where `POW` looks for directories.

`/path/to/myapp` is the path to the directory where your development files are. In your case, as its in desktop the path will be `~/Desktop/your_directory`

Open up your terminal and type the following:

```
# changes directory to ~/.pow
$ cd ~/.pow 

# creates symlink (shortcut) of your_directory in .pow directory
$ ln -s ~/Desktop/your_directory
```

Now in your browser, if you go to `http://your_directory.dev/`, your application should be ready.

**Update**

As of php 5.4 there is a build in server. Which means, you can just do the following to access your website in the browser.

```
$ cd ~/Desktop/your_directory  // or whereever your php project is
$ php -S localhost:8000
```

Comment: thanks for the response. Makes more sense now. I did type those things into the terminal and then it just said "file exists". When I opened up the browser it just said the same thing "Application not found
Symlink your app to ~/.pow/test first"

Comment: so if you go to ~/.pow directory do you see the symlink there?

Comment: I don't really know....i type ls -1 and i see 5 names...all of which  are names I have tried to symlink. Pardon my ignorance, I don't get anything when i go to mydirectory.dev. it says 404 error. if i type in anyting else.dev it gives me the same application not found thing

Comment: If you get 404 error when you go to mydirectory.dev, then POW is already working. Its your ruby application that is not working. If you are getting application not found in other url, your application is not set up properly.

Comment: ok. thank you for helping me out. all i was trying to do was set up codekit so i could develop sites locally. i guess that was the wrong idea.

Comment: there is nothing wrong with using up codekit. if you define your problem in more detail, I can help you set that up. Also please consider marking this question resolved.

Comment: if you could still help me out, I would really appreciate it. was a little busy earlier, didn't see your response. basically, I am trying to run multiple wordpress servers at once. I have mamp set up and working but after this point I am lost. I tried symlinking the right folder but I keep getting nothing when i check the url, webpage not available error. I figure I am not doing the pow part correctly. BTW, when i am symlinking my directory the terminal doesnt show any sort of response or anything.